# How to optimize multiple google-api-calendars freeBussy queries

Tags: go, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a Go REST API project in which I receive a POST request with different intervals. This reflect a shop opening hours, here is an example:

```
{
    ...
    "intervals": [
        {
            "day": "1600347600",
            "starthours": "800",
            "endhours": "1200"
        },
        {
            "day": "1600434000",
            "starthours": "1300",
            "endhours": "1700"
        },
        {
            "day": "1600520400",
            "starthours": "800",
            "endhours": "1200"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The code, in which I make the requests to Google, is the following:

```
    // Some code to get the token
    
    //We treat every interval obj sent on the params
    if len(sc.Intervals) > 0 {
        for _, i := range sc.Intervals {
            //This is a necessary step as the format of the dates that the client gives me
            //are 
            dStart, dEnd, err := getDateStartAndEnd(i)
            if err != nil {
                log.Error(err)
                return responseInterval, err
            }
            //0. build search criteria
            var query = events.SearchCriteria{
                Email:          sc.Owner.Email,
                FreeBussyQuery: calendar.FreeBusyRequest{
                    TimeMin: dStart.Format(time.RFC3339),
                    TimeMax: dEnd.Format(time.RFC3339),
                },
            }
            isFree, err := calendarService.Freebusy.Query(setCalendarId(query)).Do()
            if err != nil {
                log.Error(err)
            }
            //In this function I do two things, get all the "slots" of 15m availables
            //in an given interval, then compare them to the bussy answer of Google
            //to fill a new slice with free "slots"
            freeIntervales := findFreeIntervales(isFree,dStart,dEnd)
            responseInterval.Interval = append(responseInterval.Interval,freeIntervales)
        }
    }
```

While I admit that this is probably not the most efficient algorithm, my main problem here is that, say with 8 intervals my request takes 5 seconds to execute.

Is there a better way to query Google-calendars?
Or should I maybe rework my logic here? I thought about making only one query with multiple intervals to check for google calendars, but this seems like it's not possible.

A possible solution would be for me to take the earliest and latest time and make an unique request. Would this be a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I realized why making five calls to Google when I could get away with only one? This sped up dramaticaly the speed. Before, It took 5 - 6 seconds, now 900ms - 1400ms.

I simply took the first date of the first intervale, and the last date from the last interval and ask Google to give me all the bussy details in that range.

```
    if len(sc.Intervals) > 0 {

    dStartResult, _, err:= getDateStartAndEnd(sc.Intervals[0])
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    _, dEndResultLast, err:= getDateStartAndEnd(sc.Intervals[len(sc.Intervals)-1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }

    //0. build search criteria
    var query = events.SearchCriteria{
        Email:          sc.Owner.Email,
        FreeBussyQuery: calendar.FreeBusyRequest{
            TimeMin: dStartResult.Format(time.RFC3339),
            TimeMax: dEndResultLast.Format(time.RFC3339),
        },
    }
    isFree, err := calendarService.Freebusy.Query(setCalendarId(query)).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }

    for _, i := range sc.Intervals {
        ....
        //Do some magic to get the free intervals
```